# Matching and pushing array

Tags: javascript, array, angular.js

This code works, but I feel like it's really hacky and could be done a lot better. Can anyone give some advice on how this could be neater?

```
$scope.arrays = function() {
        $scope.committees = [];
        $scope.employees = [];

        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.php'}).success(function(data) {
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                $scope.committees.push(value);
            })

            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data2.php'}).success(function(data){
                angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                    $scope.employees.push(value);
                })
                $scope.arr = new Array();
                for (var i = 0, committee; committee = $scope.committees[i]; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0, employee; employee = $scope.employees[j]; j++) {
                            if (committee.code === employee.code){
                                $scope.arr.push({
                                    "committee" : committee.name,
                                    "color": committee.color,
                                    "members": committee.members,
                                    "femaleAnnual" : employee.femaleAnnual,
                                    "maleAnnual" : employee.maleAnnual,
                                    "totalAnnual" : employee.totalAnnual,
                                })
                            }
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }

    $scope.arrays();
```

Edit: Sorry I should have been clearer! What I'm trying to do here is merge 2 arrays if they have the same value for 'code' - and then push that array to the scope.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. It would help reviewers more if you include more context in your question, especially what your code does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of the fact that `push` accepts more than one argument so you only call `push` once. Build the arguments array and use `apply`.

```
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.committees, Object.keys(data).map(function(key){
  return data[key];
}));
```

Or if you're just putting values instead of actually appending to the existing array:

```
$scope.committees = Object.keys(data).map(function(key){
  return data[key];
});
```

Now for the AJAX part, you don't need to have a sequential request, that's that last thing you'd want to do in AJAX (besides making them synchronous). You'll need something like `Promise.all` or jQuery's `$.when`, fire them at the same time and resolve when all is done.

```
var comitteePromise = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.php'});
var employeePromise = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data2.php'});

Promise.all([comitteePromise, employeePromise]).then(function(values){
  var committees = values[0];
  var employees = values[1];
  ...
});
```

The further I look into your code, what you're just doing is merging the data from both arrays. You can build a lookup for one array, and iterate the other. That way, two loops and not to the power of two loops.

```
var comitteePromise = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.php'});
var employeePromise = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data2.php'});

Promise.all([comitteePromise, employeePromise]).then(function(values){
  var committees = values[0];
  var employees = values[1];

  // Use the committee code (assuming it's unique) as a key for lookup
  var committeesByCode = committees.reduce(function(carry, committee){
    carry[committee.code] = committee;
    return carry;
  }, {});

  // For each employee, lookup the committee and add in the data
  $scope.arr = employees.map(function(employee){
    var committee = committeesByCode[employee.code];
    return {
      committee: committee.name,
      color: committee.color,
      members: committee.members,
      femaleAnnual: employee.femaleAnnual,
      maleAnnual: employee.maleAnnual,
      totalAnnual: employee.totalAnnual
    };
  });

});
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the explanation - works much faster than my original code.